# Handling TimeSpan Exception in c#

Tags: datetime, exception, c#-2.0, timespan

I have these below lines of code.

```
if (TimeSpan.ParseExact((VSFlexShift.get_TextMatrix(VSFlexShift.Row, 2)), @"hh\:mm\:ss", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture) > TimeSpan.MaxValue)
```

which i wrote to check if the end user types the time as `12:68:56` Some what like this it should `return;`. 
But what is happening right now is the code directly catch the `Exception`. Is there any way so that i can handle it inside the loop only rather than its going to `Catch(Exception ex)`.

Exception Message:

> The TimeSpan could not be parsed because at least one of the numeric
>   components is out of range or contains too many digits.

Comment: You can use `TimeSpan.TryParse` or `TimeSpan.TryParseExact` method to check your input is valid value or not.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're looking for the equivalent [`TimeSpan.TryParseExact`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan.tryparseexact(v=vs.110).aspx) which returns a `bool` instead of throwing an exception:

```
TimeSpan timeSpan;
if (!TimeSpan.TryParseExact(VSFlexShift.get_TextMatrix(VSFlexShift.Row, 2),
    @"hh\:mm\:ss", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, out timeSpan))
{
    // TimeSpan isn't valid.
}
```

Regarding the `> TimeSpan.MaxValue`, I'm not really sure why what you're trying to check, but a `TimeSpan` object can't be larger then it's own maximum value.